# How to prevent force push for a branch that might have been rebased

Tags: git

- two people are working on a branch
- one rebases the branch and force-pushes
- the other did not notice the rebase and does:

  - `git fetch`
  - `git rebase origin/master`
  - `git push --force-with-lease`

The idea was that `--force-with-lease` should prevent you from overwriting remote branch when it's unsafe. But in this scenario it does not work because the fetch.

How would you prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

That is not how `git push --force-with-lease` works. `git push --force-with-lease` was designed to avoid the following scenario:

```
# developer B
git checkout feature-branch
git commit -m "add part B"
git fetch # make sure no changes were made by developer A
git rebase origin/master # rewrite history for some reason
# developer A
git checkout feature-branch
git commit -m "add part A"
git push
```

If developer B now runs `git push --force` , he will throw away the work just pushed by developer A, since that work was added **after** B ran `git fetch`.

- `git push --force` would pass, thus throwing away developer A's work
- `git push --force-with-lease` would not pass (since `origin/feature-branch` has changed), thus preventing developer B from crushing A's work.

---

The underlying idea is that developer B is smart enough **not** to throw away developer A's work when rebasing.

I don't know of any pure `git` features that prevents **force** pushes on a branch, but most repository management services (bitbucket, gitlab, github, ...) will allow you to prevent force pushes on certain branches.

---

### tip

I created a small script `git-diff-remote` which I put in `/usr/bin`:

```
#!/bin/bash
git fetch
git diff "$@" @{u} HEAD
```

now I always run

```
git diff-remote
```

which shows me **what I will crush** when running

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

Comment: But since your `diff-remote` script does a `fetch`, it defeats the purpose of `--force-with-lease`. You could just use `--force` after you know what you will destroy.

Comment: Why `--force-with-lease` does not work is expected. I've been using something like diff-remote as well. Problem with it is that it diffs not only the branch difference, but also "master" difference. So it's practically useless when large feature was merged in the meantime. Then diff-remote will show diff against upstream AND the whole merged branch :(

Comment: @j6t true :) I hadn't thought of it that way yet but you are right. But I do feel safer visualising what I will crush

Comment: @TomášFejfar `--force-with-lease` does work as expected, just not like **you** expected...

Comment: I worked around the "show whole newly merged master commits" using this:
`rdf = "!rdf() { git range-diff origin/master $(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name --abbrev-ref=strict HEAD@{u}) $(git current); }; rdf"`. But it still does not solve the original scenario :(